# C - execlp function call - can I have the argv point to more argument

Tags: c, exec

The way to call execlp is shown in the following:

```
int execlp(const char *file, const char *arg, ...
                       /* (char  *) NULL */);
```

For example,

```
execlp("/bin/Binary","Binary","0x00","0x01","0x02",(char *)0);
```

In this case, since my argument `"0x00"`,`"0x01"` and `"0x02"` are always fixed. Can I create a char array instead of doing it this way ?

```
char *myArgv[]={0x00, 0x01, 0x02};
```

And then

`execlp("/bin/Binary","Binary",myArgv,(char *)0);`

This one doesn't work because it will read only the first element in the array.

Please advise.

Comment: What makes you think the string literal `"0x00"` and the integer constant `0x00` are interchangeable?

Comment: yea, i know and that's why I asked. thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are looking for [`execvp`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/exec.html):

```
int execvp(const char *file, char *const argv[]);
```

---

But mind [EOF](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3185968/eof)'s comment: `0x00` and `"0x00"` are most definitely not interchangeable.

#### EDIT

As pointed out in the comments, the array passed in this case to `execvp` must contain a `NULL` pointer as the last member (unlike your example that is).

Comment: It is important to point out that in this case, the `argv` array must contain the `NULL` terminator.  The question hypothesized that it would not.